# Solr not starting on DSE 4.8.3 Single Node Cluster

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have created a Single node DSE Cluster.

In /etc/default/dse,

```
SPARK_ENABLED=1
SOLR_ENABLED=1
```

When I start dse as service, Spark shell fine when dse spark is used. For Solr, when I type the ip_address:8983/solr/ on the web browser, it says "Failed to open the page." Earlier when I was doing the same on the Web Browser, it would download an empty text file and no Solr page opened.

I have used both the floating IP Address and the internal IP Address.
There are no errors reported in the logs /var/log/cassandra/system.log
The owner:group for /var/log/cassandra and /var/lib/cassandra is recursively set to cassandra:cassandra

Any way I can solve this issue?